# How to set VideoCapture to app local storage

Tags: android, android-camerax

I have an app using CameraX to record video. When I set the output location to be the normal, external photo gallery location, it all works fine. For example:

```
val outputFileOptions = VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
        this.contentResolver,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, //Use this to save in normal Gallery
        contentValues
    ).build()

    videoCapture?.startRecording(
        outputFileOptions,
        cameraExecutor,
        object : VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback {
            override fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: VideoCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                Timber.i("onVideoSaved outputFileResults: $outputFileResults")
            }

            override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                cause?.printStackTrace()
                Timber.e("onError message: $message cause: $cause")
            }
        })
```

...will work just fine.

When I try to set it using an app local location though it crashes with:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///data/user/0/com.company.appname/files/VIDEO_20210228_153240.mp4

Now, that file works perfectly for other things like feeding it to MediaRecorder as an output location.

This is how I did that:

```
    val file = createVideoFile() //Creates the file mentioned above
    val uri = file.toUri()

    val outputFileOptions = VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
        this.contentResolver,
        uri,
        contentValues
    ).build()
```

Does anyone see what it is I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Have you tried [the `builder()` function that takes a `File`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/video/OutputFileOptions#builder(java.io.File))?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I looked at that though and couldn't find any way to use the file version and still supply the other parameters (the contentResolver and the contentValues) that it needs. There is no way to set them but through the builder that I could see.

Comment: If you are saving to a file, you do not need those other parameters.

Comment: By golly that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use build with file like that

```
val build = VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(File("/sdcard/Download/video_$timestamp.mp4")).build()
```